# find the area of the integral bound by the triangle with vertices $(0,1),(1,2),(4,1)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

ginve $\int\int3y^2$ and the triangle in the title find the integral, integrating isn't the hard part the bounds are, I wanted to integrate as a type I so my bounds were $D= {(x,y) \vert 0\leq x\leq4,1\leq y\leq2}$ I eneded up with 28 and it was marked wrong maybe if we think of each vertice as a function say (0,1) is on the y-axis maybe we can say it is bound by the line x=0 and since (1,2) lies on the line y=2 we can say it is bound by that curve as well and finally since (4,1) or I could get three lines between all the vertices I get the lines $y=x+1$, $y=-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{7}{3}$ and $y=1$
As a type one it is very clear that the x bounds are from 0 to 4 the hard part is the y bounds. I think the way to go is use the first two functions and my investigation I found that $y=x+1$ is greater than $y=-\frac{1}{3x}+\frac{7}{3}$ so I will try this:

$\int_0^4\int_{y=-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{7}{3}}^{y=x+1} 3y^2$

which gives $\int (x-1)^3- (-\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{7}{3})^3 dy$

$\int_0^4 x^3+4x^2+3x+1-(-\frac{1}{27}x^3+\frac{28}{27}x^2-\frac{175}{27}x+\frac{196}{27})$

$\int_0^4 \frac{28}{108}x^4-\frac{80}{81}x^3+\frac{256}{54}x^2-\frac{169}{27}x \Big \vert_0^4$
which gave 108.0493827 Not sure what that is as a fraction but I think a fraction would be a better answer

Comment: You want to split the integral into two regions, one that it is for $0 \le x \le 1$ and the other as $1 \le x \le 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw your region.

If you want to integrate with respect to y first, you will need to break your integral in two.  If you do it this way, $y=1$ will be the lower bound throughout, but the upper bound has two different functions for different values of $x.$

I suggest you integrate with respect to x first.

The lines that bound your region.

$y = 1\\ y = x+1\\ 3(y-2)+(x-1) = 0$

But if we are integrating with respect to $x$ first we need to isolate $x.$

$x = y-1\\ x = -3y+7$

$\int_1^2\int_{y-1}^{3y+7} 3y^2 \;dx \;dx$

If you insist on integrating with respect to $y$ first.

$\int_0^1\int_1^{x+1} 3y^2 \;dy\;dx + \int_1^4\int_1^{-\frac 13 x+\frac 73} 3y^2 \;dy\;dx$

[image]

Comment: Okay the thing I don't understand is why integrating with respect to y ends up breaking up the integral. is it because if we trace lines horizontal to the y axis and the two lines intersect at the top that the lines end up running along two lines?

Comment: Check out the picture.  Does that help?

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to convey so your picture makes perfect sense